# CKEditor event when deleting an element?

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor

Is there a way in JavaScript (or CKEditor) to detect when an image is removed from CKEditor. 
I need it for a caption element which is inserted together with the image, but once I delete the image, the caption should be deleted aswell.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no special event like a `onDelete` or `onImageRemovedFromContent`. But there are few events that can help you.

```
editor.on('afterUndoImage', function( e ){ ... } )
```

But `afterUndoImage` fires only on `Undo` command, does not fires on manual deleting of elements.

```
editor.on('afterCommandExec', function( e ){ ... } )
```

CKEditor changes content with `execCommand` (mostly), so that fires on many content's change, so you can check the diff with regex for example.

Also you can use plugin [onchange](http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com/2011/03/onchange-event-for-ckeditor.html) to detect the changes of contents, it combines `onUndo`, `onRedo`, `afterCommandExec`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use the plugin--> https://github.com/shibbirweb/ckeditor5-image-remove-event-callback-plugin

This plugin enables you to pass your own callback function which will be called when you will remove the image from your editor. I implemented this in VueJs and after having spent a couple of hours, I realized it was quite easy to do so. Its a cool plugin if you ask me. The below code snippet demonstrate the non-Vuejs way to implement this. You can write back to me if you need to know the VueJs implementation.

Thanks

P.S. : This code snippet is from the package documentation and that's all the info there is.

```
import ImageRemoveEventCallbackPlugin from 'ckeditor5-image-remove-event-callback-plugin'; // Add this
// ...

ClassicEditor.builtinPlugins = [
    // ...
    ImageRemoveEventCallbackPlugin
    // ...

]
ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {
    //... 
    imageRemoveEvent: {
        callback: (imagesSrc, nodeObjects) => {
            // note: imagesSrc is array of src & nodeObjects is array of nodeObject
            // node object api: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_node-Node.html

            console.log('callback called', imagesSrc, nodeObjects)
        }
    },
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is rather old, but I ended up here while searching a solution, so I think it's worth to post another approach.

I didn't want to monitor all possible changes, since most of the activity I forsee in my widget is normal editing or widget creation from external sources, so I ended up simply monitoring the events that would cause the deletion:

```
    editor.widgets.on( 'instanceCreated', function(evt) {
        let widget = evt.data ;
        if (widget.name === 'mywidget') {
            widget.on('select', function() {
                widget.on('key', function(evt) {
                    if ( evt.data.keyCode == 46                       // Delete
                         || evt.data.keyCode == 8                     // Backspace
                         || evt.data.keyCode == CKEDITOR.CTRL + 88    // Ctrl-X
                    )
                        jQuery(widget.element.$).myCallback() ;    // callback defined as a jQuery function for the sake of simplicity
                }) ;
            }) ;
            widget.on('deselect', function() {
                widget.on('key', function(evt) {
                }) ;
            }) ;
        }
    }) ;
```

Of course the callback has to assume that the calling widget has not been deleted yet, but that's an advantage, since one typically needs its data.