# How can I get tag name when delete it in CkEditor 3

Tags: ckeditor

I have DOM like this in CKEDITOR 3

`<div style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="embed-container">
        <img src="http://ducpt1.st.public.editor.vnexpressdev.net/original/images/blank.png" title="Video" />
    </div>
</div>`
When I choosed img and deleted it, how could I check it is img tag ???

Sorry for my bad Endlish !!!

Comment: Please show how you delete it. If you delete it manually by clicking on it and pressing delete, why do you need the tag name? This question looks a little like an XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I just choosed it and press delete or backspace keys. I need to know tag name to change parent node class. Thanks for answer

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446367/ckeditor-event-when-deleting-an-element - However, I think that what might be best would be to create a widget plugin for your needs. It's hard to say and depends on your requirements but I see that this would be a little too difficult and there surely is another easier way than editing a class definition. What about post processing for example? I don't understand why you need the class to change.

Comment: My website have CSS(height) for div.embed-container. If I just delete img, content will become <div class="embed-container">&nbsp;</div> so when website render, it will be have space empty :(

Comment: Oleq's answer seems legit, but I would still try to find a workaround, such as post-processing the data with jQuery before saving or changing the CSS structure instead of attaching to a CKEditor system.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like that ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/KXf53/)) but still it lacks support for undo manager, etc. so it's not complete:

```
CKEDITOR.addCss( '.foo { outline: 1px solid red }' );

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    allowedContent: true,
    toolbarGroups: [
        { name: 'mode' },
        { name: 'basicstyles' }
    ],
    on: {
        contentDom: function() {     
            var editor = this;

           this.editable().attachListener( editor, 'key', function( evt ) {
               // If not backspace or delete.
               if ( !( evt.data.keyCode in { 8: 1, 46: 1 } ) )
                   return;

               // Get selected element.
               var lastElement = editor.elementPath().lastElement,
                   parent = lastElement.getParent();

               // It that's img, and parent is in DOM, append class.
               if ( lastElement.is( 'img' ) && parent.getParent() )
                   parent.addClass( 'foo' );                                 
           } );
        }
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

And anothor way to do this for anyone else

`CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (editor) {
    var edi = editor.editor;
    edi.on('key', function(event){
        if(event.data.keyCode == 8 || event.data.keyCode == 46){
            var select_element = event.editor.getSelection().getSelectedElement();
            if(select_element){
                //select_element is element what you deleted
            }
        }

```
});
```

});
`